# How to make document.addEventLister('click' working for elements having stoppropogation?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Working on an chrome extension and I need to get click events. I listening to events like

```
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
 // get ur work
});
```

The problem is it does not work if the page elements has set stopPropogation. How I can make it work?

You can see its not working by openeing the site
`https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/`
Open inspector/console
Write `document.addEventListener('click', (e) => console.log(e))`;

Now try to click here n there, it will log the output on console, but if u click 'Dropdown Button' there is no output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the third arg `useCapture` as `true` in your event listener.

```
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => console.log(e), true)
```

Comment: Much simpler than I expected.